# NSThread with class method?

Tags: cocoa, nsthread

Is it possible to run a class method (starting with a '+') in a separate thread? Normally I call the method like `[myClass myController];` I tried `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:myController toTarget:myClass withObject:nil];` without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you just need to make the target `[myClass class]` instead of `myClass`. Also you forgot to use `@selector()` around the selector name. So you want:

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myController) toTarget:[myClass class] withObject:nil];`

Comment: Thank you. The @selector part was a typo sorry. Works perfectely.

Comment: I am also doing same. But my method is being called twice

Comment: You should ask a new question @Ravee10, with the specific details of your problem